# nginx ssl problem between host and container

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx

I'm unable to connect to nginx running in my container on 443 from my host. So, to debug, I've set up a simple Python webserver that serves over SSL.

This works within the container. E.g. here's the script:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello, world!')


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, 
        keyfile="/etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem", 
        certfile='/etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem', server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

Then:

```
python3 https.py
```

and from another shell into the container I get:

```
curl -k https://localhost:443
Hello, world!
```

The server log outputs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2020 15:11:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

From the host:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
1849160a43bc        w1                  "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   sleepy_chatterjee
```

i.e. 443 should be bound between container and host.

However, from the host:

```
curl -k https://localhost:443
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:443
```

Any suggestions why I'm not connecting to the container?

UPDATE

After binding to host port 4443 to debug host problems I'm getting (with `curl -v`):

```
curl -v -k https://localhost:4443
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0xf09880)
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149999 ms for 3 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0xf09880)
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 4443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:4443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:4443
```

Comment: Did you try mapping a different port on host ?

Comment: After `-p 4443:443` I then get:
curl -k https://localhost:4443
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:4443

Comment: Check this out - 
 https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/